# Trying to get users message text from a Facebook post via feed / share dialog

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook feed dialog with javascript (v2.10 of graph).
On submission, I get the post_id returned, which I store in the db.

However, when subsequently trying to access the post via the graph - the users message field to any post is always empty:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/100006258371191_1943609602524301&fields=message&access_token=EAAFsj0tVEQ...`

The only workaround I can see is:

- request the posts permalink_url field. This references a story_fbid
  in the returned URL.

`$.ajax({
    url: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/100006258371191_1943609602524302&fields=permalink_url&access_token=" + access_token,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(fb_data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
        build_page(fb_data);

    }
});`

- extract the story_fbid number via JS

`permalink_post_id = fb_data[id].permalink_url.substring(50,66);`

- Run another graph query on the story_fbid, with the message field

`.ajax({
        url: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/100006258371191_" + permalink_post_id + '&fields=message?access_token=' + access_token,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success:function (story_data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)
        {
                console.log("___Users message text : " + story_data.message);
        }
});`

This allows the message field/text to be pulled.

This clearly isn't ideal, as it results in multiple calls into facebook and is difficult to control ajax timings/returns, etc.

Is there an easier way to obtain the user's message text from a post?

Comment: Why would you need to know what text the user shared your link with in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for joining / contributing to stackoverflow. This is an interesting question and I feel you can add value to the QA database by including your relevant code to your question. Your ajax posts an calls etc. 

It almost always results in better answers to your question.

Comment: Thanks for welcome - have added code as requested.
Building a single-page app, and looking to recreate a story/comments wall - hence looking to include users text